# Spark DataFrames: Combining Two Consecutive Rows

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with the following structure:

```
|  id  |  time  |  x  |  y  |
-----------------------------
|  1   |   1    |  0  |  3  |
|  1   |   2    |  3  |  2  |
|  1   |   5    |  6  |  1  |
|  2   |   1    |  3  |  7  |
|  2   |   2    |  1  |  9  |
|  3   |   1    |  7  |  5  |
|  3   |   2    |  9  |  3  |
|  3   |   7    |  2  |  5  |
|  3   |   8    |  4  |  7  |
|  4   |   1    |  7  |  9  |
|  4   |   2    |  9  |  0  |
```

What I'm trying to achieve is for each record, three more columns are created containing the `time, x, y` of the next one (based on `time`). The catch is we only take the next records if they have the same `id` value, otherwise the new three columns should be set to `null`

Here is the output that I'm trying to get

```
|  id  |  time  |  x  |  y  | time+1 | x+1 | y+1 |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   1    |  0  |  3  |   2    |  3  |  2  |
|  1   |   2    |  3  |  2  |   5    |  6  |  1  |
|  1   |   5    |  6  |  1  |  null  | null| null|
|  2   |   1    |  3  |  7  |   2    |  1  |  9  |
|  2   |   2    |  1  |  9  |  null  | null| null|
|  3   |   1    |  7  |  5  |   2    |  9  |  3  |
|  3   |   2    |  9  |  3  |   7    |  2  |  5  |
|  3   |   7    |  2  |  5  |   8    |  4  |  7  |
|  3   |   8    |  4  |  7  |  null  | null| null|
|  4   |   1    |  7  |  9  |   2    |  9  |  0  |
|  4   |   2    |  9  |  0  |  null  | null| null|
```

Is it possible to achieve this using Spark DataFrames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function lead.
First create window by partitioning using id column and then while calling withColumn function use column that you want to show with offset value as 1.

Something like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
val windowSpec = Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('time)
dataset.withColumn("time1", lead('time, 1) over windowSpec).show
```

You can add other columns by same way

Comment: Thanks, it worked. One more question, is it inefficient to create every column individually rather than all at once?

Comment: It shouldn't matter much if you put in multiple line if you are executing action on last dataset only.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with SQL, just create a temp view and create all the columns in one go. Check this out

```
scala> val df = Seq((1,1,0,3),(1,2,3,2),(1,5,6,1),(2,1,3,7),(2,2,1,9),(3,1,7,5),(3,2,9,3),(3,7,2,5),(3,8,4,7),(4,1,7,9),(4,2,9,0)).toDF("id","time","x","y")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, time: int ... 2 more fields]

scala> df.createOrReplaceTempView("m2008")

scala> spark.sql(""" select *, lead(time) over(partition by id order by time) timep1,lead(x) over(partition by id order by time) xp1, lead(y) over(partition by id order by time) yp1 from m2008 """).show(false)
+---+----+---+---+------+----+----+
|id |time|x  |y  |timep1|xp1 |yp1 |
+---+----+---+---+------+----+----+
|1  |1   |0  |3  |2     |3   |2   |
|1  |2   |3  |2  |5     |6   |1   |
|1  |5   |6  |1  |null  |null|null|
|3  |1   |7  |5  |2     |9   |3   |
|3  |2   |9  |3  |7     |2   |5   |
|3  |7   |2  |5  |8     |4   |7   |
|3  |8   |4  |7  |null  |null|null|
|4  |1   |7  |9  |2     |9   |0   |
|4  |2   |9  |0  |null  |null|null|
|2  |1   |3  |7  |2     |1   |9   |
|2  |2   |1  |9  |null  |null|null|
+---+----+---+---+------+----+----+


scala>
```

You can get it back as another dataframe by just assigning the spark.sql result

```
scala> val df2 = spark.sql(""" select *, lead(time) over(partition by id order by time) timep1,lead(x) over(partition by id order by time) xp1, lead(y) over(partition by id order by time) yp1 from m2008 """)
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, time: int ... 5 more fields]

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- time: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- x: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- y: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- timep1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- xp1: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- yp1: integer (nullable = true)


scala>
```

Answer (score 1):

In **scala** you can also do like this:

```
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

scala> val part= Window.partitionBy('id).orderBy('time)

scala> spark.read.format("csv").option("inferSchema","true").option("header",true).load("file:///home/ec2-user/test.csv").withColumn("time1", lead('time, 1) over part).withColumn("x+1", lead('x, 1) over part).withColumn("y+1", lead('y, 1) over part).show()
```

you can also check snapshot that i have atteched  below:

[image: running snapshot of program using windows lead function]