# calculating distance between two points with scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a DATAFRAME :

```
+----------+----------+
| longitude|  latitude|
+----------+----------+
|-7.1732833|32.0414966|
|-7.1732844|32.0414406|
|-7.1732833|32.0414966|
|-7.1732833|32.0414966|
|-7.1732833|32.0414966|
|-7.1732833|32.0414966|
```

I want to calculate the distance between a point and the successor point, for example :

```
distance between (-7.1732833,32.0414966) et (-7.1732844,32.0414406)
```

the code i have done :

```
def haversine_distance(longitude1 : Double,latitude1 : Double,longitude2 : Double,latitude2 : Double) : Double= {

  val R = 6372.8;
  val dlat = math.toRadians(latitude2 - latitude1);
  val dlog = math.toRadians(longitude2 - longitude1);
  val a = math.sin(dlat / 2) * math.sin(dlat / 2) + math.cos(math.toRadians(latitude1)) * math.cos(math.toRadians(latitude2)) * math.sin(dlog / 2) * math.sin(dlog / 2)
  val c = 2 * math.atan2(math.sqrt(a), math.sqrt(1 - a))
  val distance = R * c;
  return distance

}
```

My question is: how to browse the dataframe so that i can call the function haversine_distance using the longitude and latitude coordinates of dataframe.
Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest to create a new array column which has current row and next row using window, and then pass udf on that column, which will have all 4 inputs in an arraytype

Comment: thank you for your reply. I am new to scala and I don't know how to create a new column which contains line and  the following line . Thank you for explaining more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking into that question - [Spark DataFrames: Combining Two Consecutive Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53900097/spark-dataframes-combining-two-consecutive-rows)

You can't apply `udf` to multiple rows directly, so you'll have to use window function, to combine consequent rows, getting DF like:

```
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
| long1    |  lat1    | long2    |  lat2    |
+----------+----------+----------+----------+
|-7.1732833|32.0414966|-7.1732844|32.0414406|
|-7.1732844|32.0414406|-7.1732833|32.0414966|
|-7.1732833|32.0414966|-7.1732833|32.0414966|
```

And then you can apply `udf` you've described.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i did what you said but when i apply udf it doesn't work i get the following error: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task not serializable . The code that I did : val distance_udf = udf(haversine_distance _)
  val k = x.withColumn("Distance", distance_udf(col("origin_longitude"),col("destination_longitude"),col("origin_latitude"),col("destination_latitude")))
  k.toDF().show()

Comment: @guerninekhadija did you solve "not serializable" error?